# using Redux toolkit and it is still executing the users endpoint twice when it does the refresh

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Ilm going through the "The Ultimate Authentication course with C# and React" on Udemy and got to the using redux lesson and the /users and the refresh endpoint should be only loading once but it is still loading multiple times as you can see in screenshot

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzcTD.png)

It should only be loading the users and refresh once based on the instructors' instructions. here is my code:

note: I am using the redux and the redux toolkit.

**index.tsx**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './Interceptors/axios';
import {store} from './redux/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

**axios.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`

let refresh = false;

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, async error => {
  if(error.response.status === 401 && !refresh){
    
      refresh = true;
      const response = await axios.post('/Users/refresh', {}, {withCredentials: true})

      if(response.status === 200){
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`
          return axios(error.config)
      }
  }
  refresh = false;
  return error;
});
```

**store.ts**

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './authSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer
    }
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

**authSlice.ts**

```
import {createSlice}  from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    value: false
}
export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setAuth: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        }
    }
})

export const {setAuth} = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**login.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {ILogin}  from './Interfaces/Interfaces';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


export const Login = () => {
    const [login, setLogin] = useState<Partial<ILogin>>({});

    async function handleForm(arg:any) {

        try {
            arg.preventDefault();

            console.log(JSON.stringify({ ...login }))
            
            const endpoint = '/Users/Login';

            const data = {
                ...login
            };
                       
            const config = {
                withCredentials: true,
                //Credentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
              };
                    
              try {
                const response = await axios.post(endpoint, data, config);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.token}`
                }
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
              }
            
            loggedIn(true);

        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const  loggedIn = (redirect:boolean) => {
        if(redirect)
        {
            navigate('/home'); 
        }
    }

    return <main className="form-signin" style={{'width': '300px', 'margin': '0 auto'}}>
            <form>
                <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>

                <div className="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="floatingUserName" autoComplete="User Name" placeholder="User123" value={login.UserName || ''} onChange={e => setLogin({ ...login, UserName: e.target.value})}/>
                    <label htmlFor="floatingInput">User Name</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="floatingPassword" autoComplete='current-password' placeholder="Password" value={login.Password || ''} onChange={e => setLogin({ ...login, Password: e.target.value})} />
                    <label htmlFor="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                </div>

                <div className="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>Remember me&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" /> 
                </div>
                <Button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"  onClick={e => {
                handleForm(e)
              }}>Sign in</Button>
            </form>
        </main>
}
```

**siteNav.tsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
//import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
//import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
//import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from '../redux/store';
import {setAuth} from '../redux/authSlice';

export const SiteNav = () => {
    const auth = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.auth.value);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const logout = async () => {
        await axios.post('/Users/Logout', {},  {withCredentials: true});    
        
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ``;
        
        dispatch(setAuth(false));
    }

    let links;

    if(auth){
        // handle logout
        links = <div className="text-end">
                <Button href="/login"  className="btn me-2" style={{'color':'white'}} variant="outline-dark" onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>&nbsp;
            </div>
    }
    else
    {
        //handle login
        links = <div className="text-end">
                <Button href="/login" className="btn me-2" style={{'color':'white'}} variant="outline-dark">Sign in</Button>&nbsp;
                <Button href="/register" className="btn me-2" style={{'color':'white'}} variant="outline-dark">Register</Button>
            </div>
    }

    return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
            <Container fluid>
                <Navbar.Brand className="light" href="/home"><img src="logo192.png" width="62" height="62" alt="SCSFC"></img> SoCal SportFishing Club</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
                    <Nav
                        className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
                        style={{ maxHeight: '100px' }}
                        navbarScroll
                    >
                        <Nav.Link href="#action1">About</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#action1">Meetings</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#action2">Charters</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#action2">Landings</Nav.Link>

                    </Nav>
                   
                    {links}

                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

**home.tsx**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setAuth } from '../redux/authSlice';
import { RootState } from '../redux/store';


export const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch() 
    const auth = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.auth.value);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try{                    
                const {data} = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users`)
                
                setMessage(`Hi ${data.userName}`)
                dispatch(setAuth(true));
            }
            catch (e){
                setMessage('You are not logged in.');
                dispatch(setAuth(false));
            }
        })()
    }, []);

    return (<div className="container mt-5 text-center">
        <h3>{auth ? message : 'You are not authenticated'}</h3>
    </div>);
}
```

I was expecting to have the users and refresh only run once on load.

Comment: Have you checked if it's related to [StrictMode](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode)?

Comment: I did not change anything to StrictMode.  How do I check for that?

Comment: Remove `React.StrictMode` in your index.tsx

Comment: Thanks for the help that worked for me. I just don't understand why or what exactly the React.StrickMode does. Thank you!